# Upgrading CPU in Mac Pro 5.1

Tags: upgrade, mac-pro, cpu

I am planning to update my CPU on my Mac Pro 5.1 2010. As shown [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/391479/116989) the highest CPU I can get is the dual 6-core Xeon 3.46GHz. Now I wonder if this one I found [here](https://www.tradera.com/en/item/301822/339825837/intel-xeon-x5690-6-core) can be used straight away without de-lidding? I've checked and some people say that Mac Pros version 5.1 don't need de-lidding. So I am not sure if I can buy and use the one in the link earlier without having to de-lid it or I have to? I appreciate your advice.